# How to center image dynamically in android table layout

Tags: android, dynamic, imageview, center, android-tablelayout

I'm making an app and I'm dynamically adding TableRows which include 3 imageViews and one textview it looks like this (single tableRow):

```
IV1 --- TEXTVIEW ----- IV2 ----- IV3
```

(hope it will help to understand what I'm trying to achieve)
I don't have any problem with centering TextView but I can't center ImageViews I was trying to do it like this:

```
TableLayout.LayoutParams tparams = newTableLayout.LayoutParams(
    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
    Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
iv1.setLayoutParams(tparam);
iv2.setLayoutParams(fparams);
iv3.setLayoutParams(fparams);
```

but I'm getting erros wchich starts with that one:

```
11-06 16:37:06.809: E/AndroidRuntime(6578): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TableLayout$LayoutParams
11-06 16:37:06.809: E/AndroidRuntime(6578): at android.widget.TableRow.getColumnsWidths(TableRow.java:295) 
11-06 16:37:06.809: E/AndroidRuntime(6578): at android.widget.TableLayout.findLargestCells(TableLayout.java:500)
11-06 16:37:06.809: E/AndroidRuntime(6578): at android.widget.TableLayout.measureVertical(TableLayout.java:465)
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [TableRow.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.LayoutParams.html) instead of `TableLayout.LayoutParams`. You are getting a class cast exception, which means that it's trying to cast your LayoutParams into the wrong type of LayoutParams. Since the views are actually children of the `TableRow`, not the `TableLayout`, you should use `TableRow.LayoutParams`.

Comment: Now there's no errors, but it's not working, any other ideas?

Comment: I would probably use LinearLayouts instead of TableLayout. They are simpler to use in my opinion. If you have lots of rows and need scrolling, you should use a list view and have each row be a LinearLayout